# How to use a friendly id only in one namespace

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, friendly-id

I'm using the gem [`friendly_id`](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id) in rails 4 to make nice urls for my user's product listings.  It works by overriding the `to_param`.  Now it is working wonderfully in the `Shop` namespace which is the public facing part of my site however in the `Admin` namespace I'd rather be using the regular ids because I don't need them there and I'd rather the urls be shorter.

I thought this would be easy but after digging it actually seems somewhat complicated. The `to_param`, because it's part of the model, has no real concept of what controller it is being called in.  So the only option I see is to override `url_for` so it uses `id` in the `Admin` namespace.  I'm not sure how to do that and if that really is the best coarse of action because messing with `url_for` seems a little dangerous.

Answer (score 1):

With FriendlyId5 finders are not overwritten by default.

```
friendly_id :foo, use: :slugged # you must do MyClass.friendly.find('bar')
# or...
friendly_id :foo, use: [:slugged, :finders] # you can now do MyClass.find('bar')
```

This way, I guess you can use the first option, and depending on the namespace call
`MyClass.friendly.find('params[:id]')`
or
`MyClass.find('params[:id]')`

Comment: This is untested, so tell me if I'm missing something which renders this answer useless

Answer (score -1):

You might want to use friendly_id in case if you do not want to mess with to_params. It is easier to implement to make excellent friendly urls that are both machine and human friendly 
http://kapilrajnakhwa.com/blogs/user-friendly-urls-with-friendly_id-gem-in-rails-4